applinks not showing in swcutil_show.txt
I have a React Native (RN) application that supports App Links (Universal Links) functionality. Whenever I upload the application to our TestFlight, everything works as expected, and data for the App Links is shown in the swcutil_show.txt file.
The problem arises when we create a new build (from the same code that is deployed in our TestFlight) and provide it to an external team for upload. The Universal Links do not work, and nothing is logged in the swcutil_show.txt file, no matter what we do. I suspect that re-signing the application with a different bundle identifier has something to do with the issue, but I have no knowledge in this area, nor can I find a way to debug this functionality.
